# BATCH- rename several files with incremental value relative from the oldest date to the newest

Tags: sorting, batch-file, rename

I currently need to rename several xlsx;xlsm;csv file.
I need them to have the name "Export_X_DD.MM.YYYY_HH:MM:SS.csv"
Where X is my variable from the oldest to the newest file

To give you an example:

Export_1_20.04.2001_05.35.csv

Export_2_20.04.2001_10.36.csv

Export_3_30.10.2021_07.40.csv

Export_4_05.07.2022_10.35.csv

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "C:\**MYPATH**"

set "increment=1"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /t:w *.csv *.xlsx *.xlsm') do (
    set "filename=%%~na"
    set "extension=%%~xa"

    REM Get the timestamp of the current file
    for %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "timestamp=%%~tb"
        set "timestamp=!timestamp:~6,4!!timestamp:~3,2!!timestamp:~0,2!!timestamp:~11,2!!timestamp:~14,2!!timestamp:~17,2!"
    )

    set "newname=Export_!increment!_!timestamp!!extension!"

    ren "%%a" "!newname!"
    set /a "increment+=1"
)

endlocal
```

The problem is I have troubleshoot while renaming with separators, and it's still ascending and not descending.

There is my result :

Export_4_200420010535.csv

Export_3_200420011036.csv

Export_2_301020210740.csv

Export_1_050720221035.csv

Comment: `/o-d` in the `dir` command sorts in reverse-date order (newest first). `/od` would sort oldest first so the numbering should be as desired.

Comment: You don't need lines 9, 10, 13, 15, 16, or 18, if you change line 14 to use `%%~ta` and line 20 to replace `!newname!` with `Export_!increment!_!timestamp:~6,4!!timestamp:~3,2!!timestamp:~0,2!!timestamp:~11,2!!timestamp:~14,2!!timestamp:~17,2!%%~xa`.

Comment: Perfect, it's working, and it's way easier to code like this ^^" thanks a lot @Compo